# How to convert string column to a date column in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

a varchar column is storing date value in table_a and it looks like '24-May-2021'

now i am trying to select to_date(varchar_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from table_a, but was throwing below error:

Can't parse '24-May-2021' as date with format 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

please help

Answer (score 2):

looking the the [date formatting table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions)

You should use:

```
select to_date(varchar_column, 'DD-MON-YYYY') from table_a;
```

because `May` is not `05` which the `MM` format expect, and `-` is not that separator you have in your data.